# How to send a new product to Action in Struts 2

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts2, model-driven

It looks like basical, but I am new with Struts2.

I want to send a new product created with name, price and category.

I work with struts2 version 2.5.26, Maven, tomcat 9.0, java jdk 1.8.0_241

It seams that the code I use to send the product is wrong, and `Action` defined in `struts.xml` can't get it.

**My JSP file to send the product :**

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Nouveau produit</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Ajouter un nouveau produit</h1><br><br>
<form action="newProduit.action" method="post">
    <div >
       <s:textfield name="produit.nom" label="Nom " />
    </div><br>
    <div>
       <s:textfield name="produit.prix" class="formH len150" label="Prix " />
    </div><br>
    <div  style="position:relative;">
        <label for="cat" class="formH len150">Catégorie :</label>
        <select id="cat" name="produit.categorie" class="formH len150">
            <option value="">--Choisir--</option>
            <s:iterator  value="categories" var="c">    
                <option value=" ${c.id } " > ${c.nom } </option>
            </s:iterator>           
        </select>
    </div><br>
    <div >
       <s:submit class="btn btn-vert" value="Envoyer" />
    </div><br>
    <div >
       <s:a href="listeProduits.action" class="btn" >Retour liste produits</s:a> 
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The `struts.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="actionsDiverses" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/actions" >
   <!-- other actions -- >
   <action name="newProduit" method="nvProduit" class="actions.ProduitsAction">         
        <result name="success" type="redirect">listeProduits</result>           
    </action>      
   </package>
</struts>
```

**The `ProduitsAction.java` file :**

```
package actions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven; 
import entities.Produit;
import services.IMetiersBoutiqueFactory;
import services.MetiersBoutiqueFactory;
public class ProduitsAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private IMetiersBoutiqueFactory services = new MetiersBoutiqueFactory();
   private Produit produit;  

   public String nvProduit() {
      try {
        services.ajouterProduit(produit);
      }catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
      }
      return SUCCESS;
   }    

   // other methods, properties, getters and setters

   public Produit getProduit() {
      return produit;
   }

   public void setProduit(Produit produit) {
      this.produit = produit;
   }    

   @Override
   public Produit getModel() {
      return produit;
   }
}
```

**The error sent is :**

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: No result defined for action actions.ProduitsAction and result input
```

I tried some other solutions but the best I get is a product with `nom=null, prix=null, categorie=null`.

I guess my problem is in these files.
I may send you the other files or methods

**The entity `Produit` :**

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "produit")
public class Produit {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
   private Long id;
   private String nom;
   private Double prix;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id_categorie", nullable=true)
   private Categorie categorie;

   public Produit(Long id, String nom, Double prix, Categorie categorie) {
      super();
      this.id = id;
      this.nom = nom;
      this.prix = prix;
      this.categorie = categorie;
   }

   public Produit() {}

   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getNom() {
      return nom;
   }
   public void setNom(String nom) {
      this.nom = nom;
   }
   public Double getPrix() {
      return prix;
   }
   public void setPrix(Double prix) {
      this.prix = prix;
   }
   public Categorie getCategorie() {
      return categorie;
   }
   public void setCategorie(Categorie categorie) {
      this.categorie = categorie;
   }
}
```

Comment: Most interesting thing how did you add options to your list?

Comment: Roman C, I get the list of Products with their Category without any dificulties : `   private List<Produit> produits = new ArrayList<>();  public String listProduits() {this.produits = services.listerProduits(); return SUCCESS; }` . But, maybe you mean something else ?

Comment: First error found : Struts don't accept decimal numbers with dot (3.50 => 3,50) : If I remove the category (I pre-define the "fruit" category) and enter a decimal number with a comma, it works ! So there is an other mistake with category. I tried    `<s:select name="produit.categorie" list="categories" listKey="id" listValue="nom"   label="Catégorie "  />`: it doesn't work....

Comment: Why do you enter dot if it is not a decimal separator in your locale?